# Tex4ht options to convert beamer slides

Tags: beamer, conversion, tex4ht

I tried to used `tex4ht` utility to convert beamer-latex presentation to OpenOffice ODT, and I'm really not happy with the results. Please find below the snapshots of PDF and ODT files.

[image]
[image]

Please note, Word and Acrobat Reader place pages in a different order, anyway there are few important issues observed after conversion:

1. The page breaks are not inserted between the slides, and the title of the second slide appeared on the first one and so on.
2. The image size is not in accordance with `height` option to `\includegraphics`, furthermore the aspect ratio is changed.
3. One slide with plain list disappeared completely.

The only purpose of this conversion is sharing with colleagues, so that they can copy-paste text and images. Therefore I do not expect one-to-one correspondence of  PDF and ODT, but at least it should be possible to understand the content of the presentation. Could anyone suggest which options shell I use to achieve this?

So far I used the following command:

```
mk4ht htlatex simple.tex "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo -cvalidate"
```

And `simple.tex` file is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

%% include pictures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{
  {pics/}
}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}

%%% title page
\title{Simple slides with beamer}
\author{John Smith}
\date{19 Jul 2013}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{A frame with figure}{and subtitle}

  \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{simple_cos}

  The PNG file has resolution of 640x480.

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{A frame with plain list}

  There is a plain list, nothing special:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Important point
  \item Another important point
  \item And final important point
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{A frame with overlays}

  \framesubtitle<1>{sin(x) first}
  \framesubtitle<2>{cos(x) first}

  \includegraphics<1>[width=0.5\textwidth]{simple_sin}
  \includegraphics<1>[width=0.5\textwidth]{simple_cos}
  \includegraphics<2>[width=0.5\textwidth]{simple_cos}
  \includegraphics<2>[width=0.5\textwidth]{simple_sin}

  This note is shown on both overlays.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After substituting example images, I can compile the pdf by removing some of your config. Running the conversion command results in error after error after error, though. Mostly about pgf.